# How to create buttons dynamically in Android?

Tags: android

Here the xml is like this

```
<com.example.MyViewGroup 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/screen" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</com.example.MyViewGroup>
```

And the class `MyViewGroup` extends `ViewGroup`. 
So my question is it possible to create buttons programmatically and add it to view?

Comment: You can do easily by using your java file. in which `Button` object can be used for regarding purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can use [addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method

Here is the simple example:

```
MyViewGroup mvg = (MyViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.screen);
Button btn = new Button(context);
btn.setText("My Button");
mvg.addView(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Beam_Light);
            LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context);
            final View root = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.sv_contact_info_fragment, container, false);
            LinearLayout dynamicLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.beam_contact_info_fragment_lchild);
            View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.sv_header, null); 
            dynamicLayout.addView(view);
    }
```